# Proving that unit quaternions are a 3 Manifold

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, quaternions

I am very new to topology, and I am having trouble on how to prove if something is a manifold or not. The question states that:

Let Q donate the set of unit quaternions
(a) Show that Q is a 3-manifold.

In general, I would also like to know how to go about proving if some set is a manifold or not. Thanks!

Comment: What's your definition of manifold?

Comment: First, figure out how to define the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a manifold. I like using stereographic projection to do this. Next, show that the set of unit quaternions is a unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: We are taught the following definition of manifold:                                                                                                                                                      A set S is a k-dimensional manifold if it is locally homeomorphic to Rk, meaning that each point in S possesses a neighborhood that is
homeomorphic to an open set in Rk

Comment: Have you learned the Regular Value Theorem? That's the easy way to show that something like this is a manifold

Comment: Or maybe you've learned something like it under a different name, like the Implicit Function Theorem?

Comment: yeah, I have gone through the Implicit function theorem. The thing is, I am studying this as part of a course on robotics rather than a pure differential geometry course. So, my understanding of the concepts is limited.

Comment: @NathanielMayer So, according to my understanding implicit function theorem tells me that if F(q0, q1, q2, q3) = 0 and \frac{\partial F}{\partial qi} ~= 0 then we can write the remaining three qs as function of qi. This means that we quaternion is a 3 dimensional manifold embedded in 4 dimensions. Is my understanding of Impicit function theorem in relation to this question correct?

Comment: Almost, but not quite. If $\frac{\partial F}{\partial q_i} \ne 0$ at a particular point then locally the set $\{F=0\}$ is the graph of an implicit function giving $q_i$ as a function of the others, not the other way around. But yes, that shows it's (locally) a 3-manifold.

Comment: So for this problem you need to find the appropriate $F$ so that $F=0$ describes the unit quaternions, and then show that at each point one of the partial derivatives of $F$ is nonzero, so you're locally a manifold there.

Comment: As we are considering unit quaternions, F = q0^2 + q1^2 + q2^2 + q3^2 - 1 = 0. I guess this would be the appropriate F. I will think about how to show that at each point one of partial derivatives of F is nonzero.

Comment: So $\frac{\partial F}{\partial q0} = 2q0 $ It will not be non-zero, when q0  ~= 0. If q0 = 0, we can use partial derivative of q1 and if q1 is also zero we could use q2 and so on. But, as we are using unit quaternions all the partial derivatives can't be 0 as a unit quaternion can't be equal to (0, 0, 0, 0). Hence the set of unit quaternions can be described by using multiple 3 manifolds. is this proof enough? @NathanielMayer could you please comment on this proof. Thank you!

Comment: Yep, exactly right. I guess I would say it can be described using multiple "charts" or "patches", making it one 3-manifold. But yeah that's the proof!

Comment: @Deane Why not an official answer?

Comment: @PaulFrost, I was hoping someone else would write up the details. But I'll do it.

Comment: Actually, I don't have time. Here are some other remarks: Regarding the other comments, it's possible to use the implicit function or regular value theorems, but it's overkill for this particular example. Everybody should learn how to show a sphere is a manifold using stereographic projection. The formulas derived are extremely useful later for other purposes. For one thing, they show that the sphere with the standard Riemannian metric is conformally flat.